# CSS background-image doesn't show with meteor

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, meteor

I'm trying to create a simple meteor project based on the [leaderboard example](http://www.meteor.com/examples/leaderboard) in their site. I want to add a small icon next to the score of each player. For doing so I created a folder named `public` and put `test.png` image there. In the css of `.player .score` I added the image as a background-image and not it looks like this

```
.player .score {
   background-image: url('test.png');
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100px;
   text-align: right;
   font-size: 2em;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #777;
}
```

When I deploy the project the image appears blank. The url for the image is not broken because if I use `inspect element` with chrome browser and go to `resources` I can see that the image was loaded.

Comment: background-image: url('public/test.png') no-repeat; should do the job, if your page is outside of the public folder and your image is into the folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things.

1) Keep in mind that for the leaderboard example, adding a background to the `.player .score` descendent selector will place the image *underneath* the score, rather than next to it.  To place the image next to the score, add an empty span to the `player` template:

```
<template name="player">
  <div class="player {{selected}}">
    <span class="name">{{name}}</span>
    <span class="score">{{score}}</span>
    <span class="icon"></span>
  </div>
</template>
```

2) You need to add a size to the span *as well as* to the background image.  In your css, style the span for your image separately:

```
.icon{
    background-image: url('test.png');
    background-size: 40px 40px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

For an image placed at the root of the `public` directory, the above results in this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem in my meteor "leaderboard" project with background image(local file) for page body.
The solution was to create a folder with name "public" inside my project and to put background image into it. This way background will become reachable by meteor `http://localhost:3000/bg.jpg`

After that I was able to use it in my CSS code as usual:

```
body {
  background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the `height` value:

```
height: 30px;
```

When you use a background image in CSS the image doesn't consume space. You have to explitly tell the div how big it should be. Especially when there is nothing in it. However big you want it use that as the height, I've just put up 30px.

Update: I've double checked this is working: here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This has to be something else causing it, perhaps with your elements around the div? or other clashing css classes?. (see the update above - with screen shot). I used your gravatar as the image's url. Check the chrome inspector to see nothing is overriding the css' values. Perhaps you also have definitions for either `.player`, &/or `.score`  on their own which override `.player .score` the class you've used